# Undefined index: tmp while moving file from temp to location

Tags: php

I got error while moving from tmp to location... Here's my code

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $album_id = $_POST['album']; 
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp'];
    $random_name = rand();

    if(empty($name) || empty($file))
    {
        echo "Please fill all the fields";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');//Error in this line
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `p_photos` (`name`,`album_id`,`url`) VALUES ('$name','$album_id','$random_name.jpg')");
        echo 'Photo Uploaded successfully!<br /><br />';        

    }

}
```

Where did i go wrong....yes there is a folder 'uploads'

Comment: The **undefined index** error would come from trying to access an index [`tmp`], such as on this line:  `$file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp'];`. Check to make sure `$file_tmp` is defined properly.

Comment: yup...ur right. where did i go wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Run `var_dump($_FILES['file']);` and see if `['tmp']` is an available index. Otherwise, use the correct one (which I think is `tmp_name`, but I haven't worked with raw file uploads in a long time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where did i go wrong....yes there is a folder 'uploads'

The key `tmp` doesn't exist, the correct is `tmp_name`, also, 
make sure the folder `uploads` is  **writable**.

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $album_id = $_POST['album']; 
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //The error is here
    $random_name = rand();

    if(empty($name) || empty($file))
    {
        echo "Please fill all the fields";
    }
    else
    {
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'uploads/'.$random_name.'.jpg');//Error in this line
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `p_photos` (`name`,`album_id`,`url`) VALUES ('$name','$album_id','$random_name.jpg')");
        echo 'Photo Uploaded successfully!<br /><br />';        

    }

}
```

---

Learn more about [php file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 1):

The property you're looking for is tmp_name, rather than tmp

Comment: Thanks...it worked!!!